# Android : Control view of another activity

Tags: android, view

My project includes a library ( aar ) with resource files.
An activity in my application ActivityA starts an activity in the lib which is ActivityB and it shows a layout which i do not have access to source. Now can i add some more views over the ActivityB layout . For eg ActivityB is displaying some images and i want to add some extra functions to that layout like button to delete image.

Answer (score 0):

If ActivityB isn't final, you can extend from it and launch your sub classed version instead of the original library one, then play around with the view hierarchy however you want, probably by overriding `setContentView` or some such.